# Make: No rule to make a header file?

Tags: c++, header, makefile

I am trying to make a project using a library named BigInt. My file structure is:

```
/Users/wen/Projects/challenge/fibonacci3/fibonacci3.cpp
/Users/wen/Projects/challenge/fibonacci3/Makefile
/Users/wen/Projects/include/bigint/<.cc files and .hh files>
/Users/wen/Projects/include/bigint/Makefile
```

The Fibonacci3 Makefile is as of

```
LD_FLAGS = 
CC_FLAGS = 

# Include libraries

include /Users/wen/Projects/include/bigint/Makefile

# Build object files

%.o: %.cc %.cpp $(library-cpp)
    g++ -c -o $@ $(CC_FLAGS)

# Link object files

fibonacci3: fibonacci3.o $(library-objects)
    g++ -o $@ $(LD_FLAGS)
```

and the bigint Makefile is as of (shortened)

```
# Mention default target.
all:

# Implicit rule to compile C++ files.  Modify to your taste.
%.o: %.cc
    g++ -c -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic $<

# Components of the library.

library-cpp = \
    BigUnsigned.cc \
    BigInteger.cc \
    BigIntegerAlgorithms.cc \
    BigUnsignedInABase.cc \
    BigIntegerUtils.cc \

library-objects = \
    BigUnsigned.o \
    BigInteger.o \
    BigIntegerAlgorithms.o \
    BigUnsignedInABase.o \
    BigIntegerUtils.o \

library-headers = \
    NumberlikeArray.hh \
    BigUnsigned.hh \
    BigInteger.hh \
    BigIntegerAlgorithms.hh \
    BigUnsignedInABase.hh \
    BigIntegerLibrary.hh \
```

however, `make` reports that it could not find a rule for a **header** file?

```
make: *** No rule to make target `NumberlikeArray.hh', needed by `BigUnsigned.o'.  Stop.
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 2]
```

What is happening here? Headers are supposed to be included, not compiled, so why is make asking for one?

Thanks in advance!

## Solution:

Instead of including the makefile, compile the sources in my own makefile. It worked! Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `make` program expects all files to be in the current directory. Since you include the second makefile into the current makefile, all files in that are relative to the current directory as well. You have to make sure that the files in the included makefile contains the correct paths.

Comment: Ahh, yes, that was the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Make gives this error when it cannot find a dependency; it then tries to build that dependency, but knows no rule to make this header file.

You might have mistyped the header file's name.

Comment: Okay. I will give it a shot on how it goes.

Comment: @YoshiHi: You probably gave `$(library-headers)` as a dependency somewhere, and `NumberlikeArray.hh` doesn't exist - or at least, doesn't exist where Make is looking for it.